# Test whether content of a cell can be found in another column

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to find out if the content of a cell can be found in another column.

ex: cell A1 `/EV-16-4028`

ColumnB:

```
/KAA/EV-27-0104
/KAA/EV-16-4028
/KAA/EV-16-2020
/KAA/EV-16-1020
/KAA/CHGCSAKFCFC05000500
/KAA/CHGC5ARRFRF03000300
/KAA/CHGC5ARRFRF02500250
```

The answer should be TRUE or FALSE and the answer must be next to the content of cell A1 (ColumnA).
The column I want to search in has 4000 lines...and is not on the same sheet.
The next step is to do the same for A2, A3 ... down the whole Column  to see if the cells in Column A has a link in the the B column- "archive".
I know how to search in one other cell(FIND) or search after a perfekt match- but how can I find a link when its not a "perfect Match"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
=COUNTIF(B1:B7,"*" & A1 & "*")>0
```

The asterisks are wildcards, so that the value in A1 can appear anywhere within the cells in the B1:B7 range.

Comment: Perfect- this works with COUNTIF! So to make sure I understand this: The "*"& before and after allows the formula to "count" regardless off what comes before and after the textstring I'm counting? Thank you for your help! Regards Ina

Comment: You are welcome! And yes, the bits before and after add a wildcard that means the searched-for text can be anywhere in the cells. Since the answer worked for you, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Drag this down column C:
`=IF((IFERROR(SEARCH($A$1,B1),"FALSE")),"TRUE")`

Note: `SEARCH` is not case-sensitive, `FIND` is.